# Debug Tab missing from property page in VS2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, properties

I recently had the debug tab go missing from the property page in VS2013 on all projects, but I am focused on debugging console applications.  I have gone through all the property pages and have not found anything on how to get the tab back.  I attached a screen shot as I would not believe this tab could go missing.  BTW - I am selecting the project property page and not the solution property page
[image]

You will see there is no debug tab.  It is greatly appreciated if you know how to get the debug tab back on the property page

Answer (score 1):

An installation of PostSharp 4.1.14 can cause this behaviour in VS2013 and VS2015.
It is fixed in 4.1.15 and is not an issue with 4.1.13.

You can confirm by disabling PostSharp from the Tools / Extensions & Updates menu, restarting and reopening your affected project.

Reference: http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2707-c-project-properties-build-and-debug-options-disappear-after-installing-postsharp-4114